# AffinityPropagation .labels_ vs .predict()

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

[image: Code of .labels vs. .predict()]

I'm doing clustering with AffinityPropagation from sklearn.

Using `clustering.labels_` produces a different (albeit almost identical) result to doing `clustering.predict` on the same training data.

Any insight into why this is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `predict` with any clustering except k-means-family.

If you do `fit`, the result is computed with affinity propagation.

If you invoke **`predict`, it is *not* actually doing AP**. Instead, it just finds the nearest exemplar for each point. That may, or may not, give the same results, as you have observed. Since near points are most likely responsible, this has a high chance of being correct - but it is not doing any form of affinity *propagation*, it is a nearest-neighbor classification to the exemplars.

k-means is fine because it uses the nearest-center logic. But that does not generally hold for clustering. In general, clustering algorithms cannot predict for out-of-sample data; you need a classififer for that.